# Glasserian Grounded Theory Building Blocks

Tags: methodology, social-science, qualitative

On reading the FAQ I was in hope this question pertaining a particular aspect of grounded theory would fall under data analysis. I appreciate if you would point me to which other community I should refer this to otherwise.

My question is of a novice on the field of Grounded Theory. I have seen and read few papers that distinguish what is and what is not, and the difference between Glausserian and Straussian Grounded Theory.

In an attempt to perform Grounded Theory from a Glausserian (or Classical as it is called) point of view, I've been trying to find what are the meaning of their building blocks. In their [website](http://www.groundedtheoryonline.com/online-seminars) the following building blocks are defined:

`indicator, incident, category, code, concept`

My question is thus of asking their meaning. Although one could believe that checking a book from them to be the simplest way, such literature, at least from the point of view from experts in my domain (Software Engineering), has been even considered to be [mystical](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2004225).

Comment: Grounded theory related questions will likely get better answers at a sociology Q&A.

Comment: ps: Whats is the link for it on the stack overflow community?

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to imply that there is a sociology stackexchange site. I meant, generally, statisticians deal with quantitative methods. Qualitative methodology like grounded theory is afaik the domain of sociologists. However, I think this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grounded_theory answers your questions, does it not?